# Сломалась кодировка русского языка Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, utf-8

В Visual Studio ASP.NET Core 7, я пишу код `app.Run(async(context) => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Привет"));` это для ответа или вывода текста, пишу в Program.cs
Но при запуске мне вместо текста непонятные символы показывае, а на английском всё в порядке, случилось это после того как я попробовала в этот текст запихнуть смайлик и запустить, до этого текст русский тоже нормально выводил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажала "да" и после этого русская кодировка стала символами
P.S. к сожалению скрин отправить не могу, только фото

Comment: Если мы пишем на кириллице, оказывается нужно об этом сообщить. Лучше этот код писать вот так: app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    var response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    await response.WriteAsync("Привет");
});

Comment: Вопрос можно редактировать

Comment: Если после сохранения что-то сбилось, просто перепишите русский текст заново, и все нормально будет. Посмотрел в свои файлы, у меня везде используется UTF-8-BOM, в студии она выглядит как _Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001_

Comment: Интересное, а какая кодировка была, по-умолчанию? ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы пишем на кириллице, оказывается, нужно об этом сообщить.

Лучше этот код писать вот так:

```
app.Run(async (context) => { var response = context.Response;
  response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
  await response.WriteAsync("Привет"); });
```